# Solr Grouping empty field

Tags: solr, field, grouping

**Edit**

I'm sorry if I did not explain well my need. I'll try to give a better explanation.

What I have : Millions of documents that have a field X , another field Y and another field Z which is not required (So it can be empty in some documents and not in others).

What I want to do : Search for docs that have the field X equals something and group them by field Z (so that only 1 document is returned for every field Z value), BUT I want documents who have field Z as empty to be included in the results (all of them), and sort the results by field Y (so I can't separate the request into two requests).

I hope that this is clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best answer I could find for my issue (from the solr mailing list users) :

The idea is to use a copy field of the field Z, and, when indexing data, if the field Z is empty, generate a unique value in the copy field. And when grouping, use the copy field instead of field Z.
(if the field Z is only needed for grouping, he can be used alone without the copy field).

Comment: I've used the same solution but it seems to me that there should be a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group.query` with `group.main` to achieve that.

For example, the query below fetches all documents with price from 0 to 10 and groups the results by popularity. Setting `group.query=popularity:[* TO *]` ensures that popularity is present. Making `group.main=true` ensures the group.query result is the main result.

`select?q=price:[0%20TO%20 10]&wt=json&group=true&group.field=popularity&group.query=popularity:[*%20TO%20*]&group.main=true`

Refer https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing

**Update**: I see the above does not work. SO recommends I edit the answer, rather than deleting my answer above and giving a new answer :-).

Can't you do 2 queries like this?

"Search for docs that have the field X equals something and group them by field Z (so that only 1 document is returned for every field Z value)"

```
q=X:1&group=true&group.field=Z
```

"I want documents who have field Z as empty to be included in the results (all of them), and sort the results by field Y"

```
q=(X:1 AND -Z:[* TO *])&rows=SOME_LARGE_NUMBER&sort=Y asc
```

Comment: This is not what I want to do, I want to have all docs grouped by a field, but docs having that field empty not getting grouped together but still included in the results

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I can't do two queries because of the necessary sorting.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to make it work by combining the `group.filed` and `group.query`, like this:

`group.filed=myfield&group.query=-myfield:*`

And the results are 2 objects, your filed and the query like this:

```
{ 
  responseHeader: { // },
  grouped: { 
     "myfield": { /// the data },
     "-myfield:*": {/// the data},
  }
}
```